# Wicket 1.5 - Browser Pdf Print from freemaker template to byte[]

Tags: pdf, wicket, freemarker

Im looking for a simple way to allow my application's user to print a PDF I generate after they click on a button. In the "onClick" of Button, I make some operation and then call a method like this

```
Map<String,Object> m = new TreeMap<String,Object>();
m.put("paper", paperObject);
Template t = getConfiguration().getTemplate(TEMPLATE_NAME_CONSTANT);
String html = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t,m);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = HtmlToPdfRenderer.print(html);
return os.toByteArray();
```

I don't want to leave the original page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ResourceLink` instead of a button. Pass it a custom subclass of `ByteArrayResource` like this:

```
new ResourceLink("id", new ByteArrayResource("application/pdf", null, filename) {
    @Override byte[] getData(Attributes att) {
        // generate your PDF here
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

Clicking on this link will generate the PDF and send it to the browser.

Alternatively, create a subclass of `AbstractResource` instead of `ByteArrayResource`, since `AbstractResource` is a bit more flexible.